# Eclipse autocompletion for Runnable working but not for Thread

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, runnable

If I type "new Runnable" and hit CTRL+SPACE, Eclipse allows me to create an anonymous inner class. However when I do the same with "Thread", it does not.

It is a bit annoying that every time I need an anonymous thread, I have to create a new Runnable and then change the "Runnable" to "Thread".

Is there a way to let Eclipse automatically create a thread as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround you could create a new **template** for the thread creation.

Eclise (at least in 3.7) alreay has one for Runnable. You can try it if you type `runnable` and then `Ctrl+Space` until the template proposals are shown.

To create a new template for `Thread`:

- Open the template view `Window > Show View > Templates`
- Select `runnable`
- Copy/Paste from the context menu
- Edit the new Template by replacing `Runnable` with `Thread`

Comment: This seems to be a great solution! I have to check tomorrow when I'm back at work if it works for me.

Answer (score 3):

I think Eclipse is doing this because `Thread` is a concrete class while `Runnable` is instead of an interface.  Eclipse may not by default allow you to create an anonymous class which extends a concreate one.

The more accepted way to create a `Thread` is to use a `Runnable` anyway which does not restrict you to the `Thread` base class:

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        ...
     }
 });
 thread.start();
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It does come. I am not sure how you're pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Strange, I checked it again and it really doesn't for me. Which Eclipse version are you running? I use Eclipse 3.7.2. for Linux.

Comment: You should do this inside the parentheses. `()`. This feature has been there since the very first version of Eclipse. It doesn't however, created a `run()` method stub for you. To circumvent this, You can get inside the body of the empty anonymous class created and press Ctrl + Space again there and select "Override run() method".

Answer (score 1):

Click "New" on this panel and create a new template. Ctrl-space will then work as you expect.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Avoid anonymous inner classes. You need thread? It does something important? Create normal class that extends thread and implements `run()`.

Moreover. Avoid creating thread instances whenever you want. User thread pools, executors etc instead.

Comment: Thanks but that is not really an answer to the question.